# w3wp.exe Search QueryProcessing All query processing components are in 'Failed' status

Tags: search, configuration, query, service, search-center

Thanks to Corona, the cheapest worker and absolute Sharepoint newbie can now get angry with a customer problem. I am grateful for absolutely ANY help.

Unfortunately, I'm slowly really desperate. For about 3 days now I've been trying to get the search running in our new Sharepoint. It was a migration from 2010 to 2016 using a migration tool. The actual migration worked great, but the search causes enormous problems. Error message in the ULS log: Search QueryProcessing All query processing components are in 'Failed' status.

[image]

The search application can be reached and does not show any index errors or the like.

[image]

The search services have already been restarted several times. The user and the password were also reset several times.

[image]

An index reset and a subsequent crawl did not help either. More than enough searchable results were also found.

[image]

Repeated deletion and restart of the search service through various different scripts as well as the configuration wizard unfortunately did not help either.

Port 808 was also released and Sharepoint CA + TimerJob + Search Services were restarted several times.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors when you're performing search? The search *Topology* looks healthy. Have you checked whether new contents (after the migration) being crawled and are searchable? You could use [PS script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spenterprisesearchstatus?view=sharepoint-ps) to diagnose the search issue

Comment: Take a look into a [similar post at](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224401/all-query-processing-components-are-in-failed-status) in this forum